# How to pass value in a Get request in React so I can apply filter on the backend?

Tags: reactjs, django, django-rest-framework, fetch

I would like to retrieve a list of filtered messages from my API to my React App.

On the backend the view for the Message Model looks like this.

```
class MessageView(viewsets.ModelViewSet):
    """View for the messages"""

    serializer_class = MessageSerializer
    queryset = Message.objects.all()

    permission_classes = [IsAuthenticated]
    def get_queryset(self):
        return self.queryset.filter(channel = self.request.channel)

    def perform_create(self, serializer):
        """ Create a new message with the user as Foreign Key"""
        serializer.save(user=self.request.user)
```

It re writes the get_queryset() function so I only retrieve the messages from a given channel which is a ForeignKey of Message.

On the React part is there any way to pass the channel object in the request so that

> channel = self.request.channel

would work?

Alternatively I could just retrieve all the messages and then filter on the frontend. But I feel like filtering from the api view would be better, or am I completly wrong?

Thanks,

Answer (score 1, accepted):

As you are willing to use only a GET request, just add it in as a query parameter and filter with it in `get_queryset`. See [DRF docs for request parsing](https://www.django-rest-framework.org/api-guide/requests/#query_params).

> request.query_params is a more correctly named synonym for
> request.GET.
>
> For clarity inside your code, we recommend using request.query_params
> instead of the Django's standard request.GET. Doing so will help keep
> your codebase more correct and obvious - any HTTP method type may
> include query parameters, not just GET requests.

Comment: Thanks for your answer, but I don't understand how I pass the 'channel' in my request from the frontend so that in the back end it can dynamically fitler from that information.
To say it in a different way, how to send a request from my react app with the channel object inside so then I can filter the query with this object in the api before sending the response.

Comment: Just add it to the url, for example: https://api.example.com/items?channel=123